# how to check if Android phone has TEE

Tags: android, trustzone

Some features of my Android app are depending on a TEE (Trusted Execution Environment / ARM TrustZone) being present on the phone. How from my Java app can I detect if this phone has a TEE installed, and if so, what vendor's TEE it is? Thanks!

Comment: What are these features? Generally the TEE is only accessable to certain system services. Some OEMs provide APIs for TEE access and for them you would need to use OEM specific APIs.

Answer (score 3):

If it's a java app and you just want to know about whether or not security hardware is present use https://developer.android.com/reference/android/security/keystore/KeyInfo.html#isInsideSecureHardware()

Comment: isInsideSecureHardware() is used to check whether key is inside Secure Hardware (e.g., TEE, SE), instead of whether TEE is supported by the phone. If TEE is supported, it will be used automatically to store keys?